# node.js res.header('location') appears to be changing https to http

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Not sure if this is a browser or node.js thing.

I'm setting (well actually oauth2orize is) the location header to `https://localhost:4000...`, the debug statement clearly shows this. This is from a https request.

However at the browser it is showing up as location: `http://localhost:4000....` I've even pasted "junk" to the end before responding and it's right there in the header, yet the https is being change to http.

I'm using a proxy here, but I somehow doubt it cares since it appears to pass other redirects fine.

```
var location = "https://localhost:4000/dashboard#access_token=BIJs8aOamYbfvz9IqCQkkhgFTnp8vvmAXmTzr6bGZSTKvQIfVP627IPXu2ZHQrQqMvDWrvtZe1aX4zR5cbmrcjLtzyUKP9PEn8XVLC43hDW8HHdmMc70YaWDMzgmueLqc9y0IqKewxmCbqkpqfPdRQ1FssyMdWfnNExowTzSU1wuIFEahUSKGg64Ip8aJzngdyKEluWNDxchaRXBsDEBPR0tvR2Eb1h9yPgkaY0ssIbYLnnFwyXwj13AThCZYacH&expires_in=3599&scope=profile&token_type=bearer"

res.statusCode = 302;
res.setHeader("Location", location + "junk");
res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'text/plain');
res.end('<p>302. Redirecting to ' + location + '</p>');
```

In the browser I'm getting:

```
Request URL:https://localhost:4000/oauth/dialog/authorize/decision
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:35
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:splashShown1.6=1; undefined=0; csrftoken=tuY3Uoh3DDfctJ92Hbjq1070072ZNwXl; connect.sess=s%3Aj%3A%7B%22passport%22%3A%7B%7D%7D.Y%2FN8%2F6JZIdX2TJ%2BTKGLvw0Fxbthv7AppwHR0GLB0EpI; connect.sid=s%3AXRVtIjxoIjzwkoCSw4tJpgBW.%2BCFrYUVKQgNoUZjUCtBopglk%2F0GHmXukTJ0UNBJZHIc
Host:localhost:4000
Origin:https://localhost:4000
Referer:https://localhost:4000/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=v10data_dashboard&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4000/dashboard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
transaction_id:xP7l0zTn
allow:allow


Response Headers
connection:keep-alive
content-type:text/plain
date:Thu, 26 Sep 2013 16:27:00 GMT
location:http://localhost:4000/dashboard#access_token=P40W1mZvSTUUk...OcsIQ9S4&expires_in=3599&scope=profile&token_type=bearerjunk
transfer-encoding:chunked
x-powered-by:Express
```

Update:

I've read up on 303 and 307 redirect codes and after trying 303, it works! Why? I'm still not absolutely sure yet, still trying to make out the specs as it appears that browsers implement in slightly different ways, but now they mostly do it the same, part of the specs are ignored... very confusing.

I've also tried it in Firefox, the 302 and 303 both give the same results as Chrome (as it was the example results shown above).